# Anomaly detection for categorical data

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, anomaly-detection

I have data which contains both categorical and continuous data. Training data is correct data by which we need  to train and check on test data which actually may contain some anomalies.
[image: Training Data]. Testing data is as: [image: Test Data]

I am trying some pyod algos like KNN, ABOD,and also One-Class-SVM but none is working on categorical data. Please suggest me some solution. I am very new to machine learning , Please suggest me some solution.
Also if you can suggest some new approach it would be great.

Comment: (1) Please do not post screenshots where text(ual table) would suffice. If really need be, cut it to the relevant part. (2) What do you mean by "anomaly" in categorical data? (3) How do you evaluate the solution, i.e. how do you know, that KNN, ABOD and other's you've tried do not work? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60333510/edit) (2) and (3) into the question.

Comment: Anomaly in categorical data means that, suppose in training data for M1 we have for steps (S11, S12, S13 , S14), it finds S15 for M1 in test data, then it should detect it as anomaly. When I am passing whole data it is saying that string can not be converted to float, that's how I know KNN and ABOD is not working